# How to append/concat a number in re.sub

Tags: python, regex

So I have a re.sub line that looks like this

```
re.sub(r'(.*_)\d*(\..*)', r'\1' + mediaFileId + r'\2', baseName)
```

mediaFileId is a string that looks like `'8000'`

This line returns `invalid group reference` because it thinks I'm looking for `\18000` when in reality I want `\1`.

This is such a simple problem but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'(.*_)\d*(\..*)', r'\g<1>8000\2', baseName)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: bah.  I guess I should pay more attention to the docs :p.  Thanks!